# Database Relationships many to many 3 way confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have a simple database aand I want to create a booking and scheduling system. It is open to change in order to reach my goal so dont worry about altering the design if needed.

Below is an ERD:

[image]

The problem is as follows:
I have members who can make a booking at a specific time (booking period) for a specific place (bookable area) The current relationship set allows many members to book many times in many places and these may overlap. i.e. it allows double bookings or people to book two places at the same time (i.e. be in two places at once).

My question is, how do I modify the design of this database to allow strictly the following:
A member can only book a single place but over multiple times (i.e. 9-9:30, 9:30-10, 10-10:30 ect). Effectively allowing members to book one place and time. Once booked, no other member should be able to book the same place and time. They can book the same place but at a different time, or the same time but a different place but not both.

What do I need to change to make this happen. I would prefer to do it in the relationships only because this leaves it obvious, however, as a last resort, if there is no way to do it using relationships, I will turn to triggers but I dont want to use these as they are not as obvious as an erd.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit 1: Triggers and check constraints are indeed accaptable as answers and I am not in any way saying this is not the norm or that it is incorrect. If this is the only way I can do it then I will just have to do it like this. However, I am asking because I would prefer to make it as obvious as possible to other programmers that this is the case, so this is why I am looking for a way to do it through relationships. However, I do accept this may not be possible. I just dont know for sure, hense the question.

Edit 2: I know I said I would like to do it without using constraints or triggers however it seems that it is not possible to do this without extream measures which will serve to overcomplicate things. However, I do like the over complicated answer as it shows some real nice thinking regarding relationships. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please notice that all the answers thus far contain Unique Keys.

Comment: I have noticed! Cheers! :-) I am going to try out each of the answers and the one that comes out the clearest (for me) will get the accepted answer. However, all have offered guidance in the right direction so I will +1 everyone as thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Original Response**

If I'm understanding correctly, the following scenario shows examples of what is and isn't allowed.

```
Member            Book Time              Book Place
-----------------------------------------------------
John              0900-1000              Room 1
John              1000-1100              Room 1
John              1100-1200              Room 1
John              0900-1000              Room 2        <--- not allowed, member double booked
Jane              0900-1000              Room 1        <--- not allowed, room double booked
```

So, what you want to force is uniqueness on two separate groups. One group is the Member and the Book Time and the other is the Book Time and Book Place.

You can create two unique keys on the `Bookings` with these columns to enforce that neither group can ever duplicate. That is, a Member with duplicate Book Time cannot repeat because it will violate the unique constraint and a Book Time with duplicate Book Places cannot repeat for the same reason.

EDIT: I see that you're wholly against constraints in this scenario, so my answer may be pointless.

EDIT2: My solution assumes that you establish a surrogate key as the primary key of the `Bookings` table. Apologies for not mentioning that.

**Alternative Option**

Here's a wacky idea that I thought of. You can maintain 6 tables.

```
Member
BookTime
BookPlace
Member_BookTime
BookPlace_BookTime
Member_BookTime_BookTime_BookPlace
```

OK, before you write me off, just hear me out! Your diagram has 4/6 of these tables. I am proposing splitting up the relationships between the Members, BookTimes, and BookPlaces.

Below has a surrogate primary key and a compound unique key to guarantee that no member is double booked for a time.

```
Member_BookTime
---------------
ID (PK)
Member_ID (CUK)
BookTime_ID (CUK)
```

And below has a surrogate primary key and a compound unique key to guarantee that no room is double booked for a time.

```
BookPlace_BookTime_ID
------------------
ID (PK)
BookPlace_ID (CUK)
BookTime_ID (CUK)
```

And below has a compound primary key and the relationship between the member's booking time and the room's booking time to ultimately tie a member to the room for a specific time.

```
Member_BookTime_BookTime_BookPlace
----------------------------------
Member_BookTime_ID (CPK)
BookPlace_BookTime_ID (CPK)
```

Does any of that make sense? In the above schema, member's cannot be double booked and room's cannot be double booked. I realize that it might be "overnormalization", but it makes the relationships a bit more clear.

The constraints suggested aren't really "hidden" because they show up in the SQL used to define the table. I understand that you want to make everything about the constraints of the data visible from an ERD, but sometimes the constraints are too complicated.

Comment: What you have suggested is correct. To clarify, are you suggesting that in my case I place unique keys on bookings.bookingperiodid and bookings.bookableareaid and then add a separate primary key to identify each booking. If so, are you sure this will meet my requirements. Again, unique keys are essentially another form of hidden constraint. Which I am not against, but would simply prefer not to use. However, if there is no other way, then what choice do I have, and I do indeed accept this is the norm. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In response to the original: you would remove the current primary key setup, create a separate auto-incrementing primary key ID on Bookings, create a Compound Unique Key on Bookings.MembersId and Bookings.BookingPeriodID, and finally another Compound Unique Key on Bookings.BookableAreasID and Bookings.BookingPeriodID. Or you can check out the edit I just made with a wacky new idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to support 30 or 15 minute intervals, we could do something like below.

The periods table would look like so:

```
   ID     StartPeriod End Period
   1      0:00        0:15
   2      0:15        0:30 
   3      0:30        0:45 
   4      0:45        1:00 
   5      1:00        1:15
```

*and so forth

So if you wanted Member 1 to book area 1 from midnight to 12:30 am  on 7/30/2012 with a booking description of "Sleep" the records would look like so

```
    BookingInfo
    Id    Description
    1     "Sleep"

    Bookings
    Id     MemberId PeriodID BookingInfoId BookableAreaId Day
    1      1        1        1             1              7/30/2012
    2      1        2        1             1              7/30/2012
```

You could then put two Unique indexes on Bookings one with MemberId,Day,PeriodId (which would prevent them from being scheduled for the same day at the same time)

and one for BookableAreaId, Day, PeriodId (which would prevent someone from double booking the same area at the same 15 minute interval on the same day)

You could also drop the Id field as the primary key on the Bookings table and replace one of the Unique indexes with a Primary key on those fields.

Sorry for the obscure formatting, I'm new to this site. Attaching the ERD as a link since I can't post a picture (until I got enough rep)

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltd2l.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would change your data model like this:

BookingPeriods would contain a list of timeslots. For example. you can book by morning and afternoon, which would make StartTime 9 am and EndTime 1 pm. Or in blocks of an hour, which means records 9am-10am, 10am-11am etc.

```
Create table BookingPeriods (
    id int primary key
  , StartTime Time
  , EndTime Time
  , Description varchar(max)
)
```

BookingAvailability would be a simple mapping between the timeslots and the Dates. So you have a list per date of which timeslots are possible

```
Create table BookingAvailability(
    id int primary key
  , Day Date
  , PeriodId int references BookingPeriods(id)
    constraint uq_bookingAvailability unique (Day, PeriodId)
)
```

BookableAreas just becomes a list of the physical locations.

```
Create table BookableAreas(
    id int primary key
  , Name varchar(100)
  , ActivityTypeId int
  , Description varchar(max)
)
```

Members stays the same

```
Create table Members(
    id int primary key
  , FirstName varchar(100)
  , ...
 )
```

Then bookings becomes the table where everything comes together. You a unique record per availability record and area. The memberid is just some side information for the record.

```
Create table Bookings(
    id int primary key
  , AvailabilityId int references BookingAvailability(id)
  , AreaId int references BookableAreas(id)
  , MemberId int references Members(id)
    constraint uq_Bookings unique (AvailabilityId, AreaId)
)
```

This data model would be used as follows:

Make sure to never register "overlaps" in the Time slots here. If you want more fine grained detail you need to create a record per hour for example.

```
INSERT INTO BookingPeriods (id, StartTime, EndTime, Description)
VALUES (1, '9:00 AM', '12:00 AM', 'Morning'), 
       (2, '1:00 PM', '4:00 PM', 'Afternoon')
```

This is a list of possible timeslots where you can book. (for example dates in the weekend are excluded)

```
INSERT INTO BookingAvailability(id, [Day], PeriodId)
VALUES (1, '20120801', 1),
       (2, '20120801', 2),
       (3, '20120801', 1),
       (4, '20120801', 2),
       (5, '20120801', 1),
       (6, '20120801', 2)

INSERT INTO BookableAreas (id, Name, ActivityTypeId, Description)
VALUES (1, 'Ground Floor', 1, 'The ground floor room'),
       (2, 'East Wing Room', 1, 'The east wing room on the first floor'),
       (3, 'West Wing Room', 1, 'The west wing room on the first floor')

INSERT INTO Members(id, FirstName)
VALUES (1, 'Barak'),
       (2, 'Tony'),
       (3, 'George')
```

Here we attempt to create the actual bookings.

```
INSERT INTO Bookings(id, AvailabilityId, AreaId, MemberId)
VALUES (1, 3, 1, 1) -- Barak books the ground floor on 20120801 in the morning

INSERT INTO Bookings(id, AvailabilityId, AreaId, MemberId)
VALUES (2, 3, 1, 2)  -- Tony books the ground floor on 20120801 in the morning --> error

INSERT INTO Bookings(id, AvailabilityId, AreaId, MemberId)
VALUES (2, 4, 1, 2)  -- Tony books the ground floor on 20120801 in the afternoon --> ok
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry to take so long to comment however I was trying out the other answers in turn. You have seen what I and others failed to see. That I would need to include the date otherwise the same people will be unable to book the same areas the same times on different days. Well spotted. Just a quick question, will your suggestion allow me to take the date into account (note, its not a requirement for the answer to be accepted, however I am leaning toward accepting oyur answer due to your forsight). If not, might you be able to suggest how to fix this and guarentee acceptance.

Comment: I have also just finished trying your suggestions, but it doesnt work at all. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. But in all three fields I can enter the same id value and get no problems which is the same as when I started. However, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I got it working, but I had to make a minor modification. Perhaps I am not reading correctly. I did have to use a unique constraint on the bookingavailability table across the day and periodid columns. Otherwise the periods would not be unique. In your example above someone could book periods 1 3 and 5 which while different periods in the table, relate to the same timeslots. I will accept your answer because of your forsight with regard to including the days and you have thus saved the the trouble of asking another question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a problem. I had to take away the accepted answer because even with everything considered, it fails to meet one of the requirements in the question. That being multiple members can book the same area at the same time (double booking). is there any way to fix this without loosing the other stuff.